# What's the archaic term for the place where swords were made?

Tags: single-word-requests

Place where blacksmith or swordsmith or metalsmith works.
Where swords are forged (together making alloys)
or
swords are cast from bronze, etc.

For example, a clinic is for doctors, or an office is.. well, ambiguous in nature. A school is for teachers.

If I had to name that "shop" would it be called a factory or a foundry, or *were* they called something different and more concise?

Comment: Under a spreading chestnut-tree / the village smithy stands; / the smith, a mighty man is he, / with large and sinewy hands.

Comment: A *forge* enables forming of metal by heating it until it is malleable. A *foundry* melts the metal and forms it in a mold. Note that companies which design fonts are often still called type foundries, even though of course they now work in software instead of metal.

Comment: Please change your accepted answer to the highest-voted one, or explain in a comment on the answer why the extremely archaic form is better for you than the correct, modern one.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes " 'were' " - The OP is looking for an archaic term. Due to specialization, not many smiths start from ore anymore, and they haven't had to for a very long time. *Forge* is incorrect (today) if the smith also "makes alloys" as that is work done in a foundry. If you *did* both, you worked in a *smithery*, as a blacksmith, tinsmith, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider, ***smithery***

> the work, craft, **or workshop** of a smith.
>
> [1615–25]
>
> [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smithery)

Comment: Also *smithy* and (notably in *Hamlet* 3.2) *stithy.* Of the three, *smithy* is much the [most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smithy%2Csmithery%2Cstithy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: "He stood there, sweating. The smithery was a hot place." OR "He stood there, sweating. The smithy was a hot place.". Which one sounds better?

Comment: Somehow my WPS writer does not give me a red line under smithy as it does under smithery.

Comment: +1 And sometimes the *armorer* (the shop being named the same as the craftsman).

Comment: Smithery is not the correct term, at all. Perhaps it was in 1625. I have never heard this as a native speaker. Forge is the correct term, smithy is archaic but passable.

Comment: @rw-nandemo thats because it is shortened to smithy. Forge is generally used for the hearth itself. Most places called 'something forge' are actually a Pub not a Blacksmith's at all.

Comment: @JamesRyan: not sure what you mean by "it is shortened to smithy." "Smithy" and "smithery" are distinct words with separate etymologies; one is not derived from the other.

Comment: just commenting that *smithy* should definitely be an answer. i'm a native speaker and have heard *smithy* numerous times and have never heard *smithery*.

Comment: @sumelic smithy has different etymologies for the different uses

Comment: Agreeing with @sgroves.  I've never heard the term "smithery" before in my life.  SGR's answer is really the best one: either "forge" or "smithy".

Comment: @JamesRyan: I didn't realize that! What are they? All the sources I looked at only mentioned one etymology, from Norse "smiðja." (For example: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/smithy)

Comment: In particular, "swordsmithery".

Comment: That's just the generic suffix "ery" applied to the compound "swordsmith". It doesn't mean that "smithery" is used in isolation.

Answer (score 50):

You could call it a **[forge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forge)**, but it's basically the same thing as a blacksmith's workshop, or a smithy. Blacksmith's is also a fairly commonly used pronoun, as in 'I'm going to the Blacksmith's later.'

> A blacksmith’s workshop; a smithy.

Comment: Plus forge brings to mind the place where the irons are actually heated, rather than the entire workshop.

Comment: A blacksmith has different skills than a weaponsmith, and uses different tools. Yeah, there's some overlap.

Answer (score 13):

Armory

> a place where arms and armor are made; an armorer's shop; arsenal.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/armory)

Comment: Commonly understood to mean the place where such weapons are _stored_, though.

Answer (score 9):

All of the answers have some merit:

In UK english 'forge' is commonly used for the entire building as well as the specific piece of equipment where metal is heated for forging. Similarly the actual heating apparatus may be called a 'forge' 'hearth' or 'fire' (when lit).

It is very common to see buildings in the UK called 'The Old forge', 'Forge Cottage' etc. Similarly working blacksmiths premises and businesses will often be called *Something* Forge.

Smithy is also correct but much less commonly used, an hardly ever for contemporary working forges.

As an aside it is also common to see the words 'forge' and 'foundry' confused. Forging involves shaping metal (usually hot) by striking with a hammer or shaped die whereas founding is casting molten metal into moulds.

Where we are talking specifically about producing weapons and armour 'armoury' and 'arsenal' may be appropriate but this tends to be more archaic for actual production of weapons and in modern usage implies more a place where weapons are stored or maintained rather than made.

Also an individual or company specialising in the production of blades could be called a cutler ( famously Wilkinson Sword) . Bearing in mind that historically the manufacture of the blades themselves would often have been separate from the hilt and other 'furniture' which were separate crafts.

This comes from my own experience of working in the blacksmithing and blade making industry in the UK.

Comment: "Smithy is also correct but much less commonly used, and hardly ever for contemporary working forges." That's what the OP's after: *non*-contemporary.

Comment: IME *forge* is also often used to refer to the entire building in American English. There was a road near where I grew up called "Drop Forge Lane". A drop forge is a special kind of forge and again, the term *drop forge* refers to the whole building.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the forge are the tools and equipment within the smithy. The place where the metal is heated. And then used on the anvil, with a hammer?

Comment: I'd tend to agree, but rather than phrasing this as a question, you should phrase it as an answer, with supporting citations such as dictionary quotes.

Comment: "'forge' is commonly used for the entire building as well as the specific piece of equipment" –Chris Johns

Comment: Maybe, but I was going on what my blacksmith husband advised me, after a lifetime of being a blacksmith.